# Macro Button for Filter

Tags: excel, vba

I recorded a macro to create a button that would filter my contracts to find only the ones with a - in them and copy and paste them into another sheet and got this:

```
Sub Contracts_Hyphen()
'
' Contracts_Hyphen Macro
'

'
    Sheets("Transactions").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AA$31579").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=Array( _
        "17030-89", "39975-41468-43641-45775-48215-49324", "40011-41747-46077", _
        "43642-45773", "43773-46237", "46078-46771", "46238-46409"), Operator:= _
        xlFilterValues
    Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Contracts").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

The problem with this code is that if I added another contract with the number for example "18936-87645" this macro would not find it. So what I changed it to was:

```
Sub Contracts_Hyphen()
'
' Contracts_Hyphen Macro
'

'
    Sheets("Transactions").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AA$31579").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="-"
    Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Contracts").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

But now with that change it is not finding anything. So how can I setup my macro to include numbers with hyphens even potentially newly added numbers?

Comment: ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AA$31579").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="=*-*"

Comment: No problem. The '*' on either side of the '-' indicates any amount of any character.